# How to change header color of the selected accordion?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I am trying to change the color of header of the accordian when it has been selected by the user.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion

Comment: Hello Debolina, Can you share the effort that you put into before posting this question on StackOverflow.  On SO, we provide some help based on your efforts and not by providing entire solution to a problem.  :)

Comment: Being a new user, the key piece of css that you're looking for is: `.panel-open .panel-heading  {background:lightblue;}` - it should work with the code in the link that you're looking for